Block structure in Shopify theme
I use theme in Shopify with name Vision. As I understood, some block was edited with code interface.
Can someone please help with advice, how and where I should to edit code, to have the same structure of block like in original theme?


If you can either use the code editor or you can directly go to the shopify Online store > Theme > clinic on the triple dots of your active theme > edit code.
After that search for the desired section (blocks resides in the section), copy the code.
Create a new section and paste the code and save.
Now you should go to the Customizer and add the section to any page.
Study how the loop works and blocks are rendering, then modify it as per your need.
